# how to create a virtual key click with a button

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to create a virtual key click (PrintScreen) with a UI button ("Capture") in Metro style app by C#.
and save the image as bitmap or to StorageFile.
How to create a event to do that? 
I'm trying to use PrintScreen, but I only found enum VirtualKey.Snapshot under Windows.System, but I don't know how to use it.

Or is there any API or method I can use directly to save PrintScreen image?
I found something VS forum, but it only works for .NET
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/79efecc4-fa6d-4078-afe4-bb1379bb968b

```
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Drawing.Imaging; 

private void PrintScreen()
{  
    Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
    printscreen.Save(@"C:\Temp\printscreen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```